# Keep Form.BackgroundImage visible in high contrast mode

Tags: c#, winforms, high-contrast

I have a .NET Winform with a background image, and testing just reported the BackgroundImage is hidden when display settings in Win7 are set to high contrast mode.  I understand why MS does this by default, but I'm hoping there is a way to override this behavior without changing the layout of my form?  I'd rather not move my click events and such to another image control that I add on top of the form to simulate a background (and then also have to move my transparent PNGs to be contained by that as well)... we are in late stage of testing, so the less changes the better.

The "background" really isn't a typical background, it has text and important content on it that should not be hidden EVER.  Sure, you can -1 me for bad design, but hey, it seemed to work up until this minor issue ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is just a guess: Will it hide the image if you use a monochrome image? You can then check at runtime ([System.Windows.Forms.SystemInformation.HighContrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.systeminformation.highcontrast) for WinForms or [System.Windows.SystemParameters.HighContrast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.systemparameters.highcontrast.aspx) for WPF) and set it to the appropriate image.

Comment: I ended up just drawing it in OnPaint: e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(BackgroundImage), 0, 0); -- if nobody else gives a better answer, I'll mark yours as the answer, since the property for checking HighContrast would have helped if I needed to go another route (like show a label with just text instead of my image).