# c# Override high-contrast for background image

Tags: c#, image, background, contrast

I wasn't able to find an answer for this:

I have a background image on my form that I want to remain visible even when the system is on High Contrast mode. Is there code that can be entered that overrides the HC mode?

I've tried this on the `Form Load` event but no luck- no definition for graphics. (Not sure this would even be a viable solution):

```
OnPaint: e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(BackgroundImage), 0, 0);
```

Aside from creating a PictureBox across my form and putting the image that way, does anyone know of a way to show the BG image of the form always?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Keep Form.BackgroundImage visible in high contrast mode](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110050/keep-form-backgroundimage-visible-in-high-contrast-mode)

Comment: What the "OnPaint" line means is that you need to put the the code in your form's `OnPaint` event handler

Comment: @GrawCube Ah, gotcha. Is there anyway to get it on the FormLoad event perhaps?

Comment: OnPaint is called every time the form is repainted, including the first time it's opened.

Comment: my bad, you'll probably want to *override* the OnPaint event. If you're just painting the background, it'd probably work in OnPaintBackground. Override the method by adding a method like this: `protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)`

Comment: I've gotten it to work, but now is the issue of re sizing the image on 'Stretch'...by default it puts the image as is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Override the [`OnPaintBackground`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
protected override void OnPaintBackground(PaintEventArgs e)
{
    e.Graphics.DrawImage(new Bitmap(BackgroundImage), e.ClipRectangle);
}
```

This [DrawImage](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.onpaintbackground%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) overload will stretch the image to fit the rectangle. If the ClipRectangle doesn't work (sorry, I can't test this right now!), create a new `Rectangle` with the background dimensions