# Background image not appearing in high contrast mode win forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a number of buttons that have background images. When high contrast mode is on you cannot see the background images. I don't want to set an image instead. Is there something I'm missing because this seems very strange?

Comment: I think this may be by design in windows. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11110050/keep-form-backgroundimage-visible-in-high-contrast-mode)

Comment: It is by design.  If you want to see it anyway then you have to draw the image yourself.  Just set DoubleBuffered = true and override OnPaintBackground().  And of course verify that contrast is not compromised by the image, it almost always does.